# Which kind of professional should I call to fix my creaking floor?

Tags: flooring, floor, squeak

Landlord worries about me screwing through pipes that run under the flooring (though I wonder whether that concern is justified). I'm not terribly gifted in DIY anyway and I'm guessing this problem requires knowledge so I'd rather pay a professional to come for a couple hours and handle it for me.

But who should I call?

Here's a video showing my creaking issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rje4mO21gR4

EDIT:
Here's the floor before and after installing floorboards: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHl2X.jpg

Comment: Call the landlord, it's their job not yours.

Comment: What kind of floor is that?  It looks like a rough synthetic board of some kind with visible surface nails - does some finished floor material go on top?  It just needs some screws instead of nails.  A carpenter or really any handyman should be able to fix that up.

Comment: It is always a risk when driving nails through the concrete as nobody can figure out where the piping is and the depth. The landlord has a legit concern, and now you are on the hook if anything goes wrong.  Also, I don't understand why use nails rather than glue in the first place. Hire a carpenter now to complete the work and wish you have the best of luck.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger I edited my question with pictures showing what you enquire about. I'm not even sure whether the creaks come from the floorboards or the thing underneath it (no idea how to call these)

Comment: Tetsujin not that kind of landlord I'm afraid. r13 screws would go into the wooden floor not in the concrete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I see nails!**

Your video shows what looks like nails.  They are holding the floor down.  Maybe they have gotten loose.

You could try tapping them down more.  That does not add anything or risk anything.  They will eventually get loose and squeak will come back but that might make things bettter for a while.

If this does not work you could take the nails out and replace with screws.  If the screw goes where a nail went (or right next to it) you will not hit a pipe or wire.

But you don't want to forfeit your deposit.  It is not wrong to ask the landlord to help with this, or send his/her handyman to take care of it.